# Algorithm for helical scan reconstruction in tomography?

Tags: tomography

What are the reconstruction steps for helical scan tomography of 3D function f(x,y,z) assuming z is sampled at nyquist rate 1/dz so that slices f(x,y,k*dz) can be defined.

Getting projections as

P (t) = $ \int f(tcos(\theta) - rsin(\theta), tcos(\theta) + rsin(\theta), \theta  /dz) dr $

Answer (score 2):

Is this for CT?  Is the imaging device a plane (cone beam tomography)?  If so, there's a helical back projection algorithm, but I think you'll have to read about it in a book; it's a bit involved.  Basically, you do a filtered back projection for each slice like in regular CT.

It's not a perfect reconstruction.